# Numbers are rounding in WordPress PieChart

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I have a WPBakery Builder on my WordPress website and I created a Pie chart. The number I want to display there is number 14.3 and on the website it is rounded and published to 14%. There is no such option in the Edge Pie Chart Settings and in Row Settings too. Where I can change the settings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It might not be a setting, but rather functions in the code that outputs the number. Did you try asking WP Bakery support? I would start there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a site for coding-related questions. If your problem is to do with your code, then please edit your question to include a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem. If you are asking about existing functionality provided by a plugin or theme then that is off topic for this site. Please review ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Daryna!

I am understand that you might have not access to code, so you should carefully read chapter named "Pie Chart" in this documentation:
https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/learning-more/content-elements/

As I understood from this wp-bakery documentation:
"*Input integer value for label. If empty “Pie value” will be used.*"

**You can use only an integer values, but not a float, as you want.**